# 'else' without 'if' despite use of braces

Tags: java, if-statement

I've been getting the 'else' without 'if' error for the following code and I'm not sure why. I've used braces and everything so I'm really confused.

```
        if(mean >= 90 && mean <= 100){
            grade = 'O';}

        else{ 
            if(mean >= 80 && mean < 90)
            grade = 'E';}

        else{ 
            if(mean >= 70 && mean < 80)
            grade = 'A';}

        else{ 
            if(mean >= 55 && mean < 70)
            grade = 'P';}

        else{ 
            if(mean >= 40 && mean < 55)
            grade = 'D';}

        else{ 
            if(mean < 40)
            grade = 'T';}
```

Comment: You can only have one `else`  per `if`. You probably meant to use `else if(...){`

Comment: Basically, `else { if (...) ` isn't the same as `else if(...) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are not using the right structure for if-else statement in java. It should be like :

```
if (testscore >= 90) {
    grade = 'A';
} else if (testscore >= 80) {
    grade = 'B';
} else if (testscore >= 70) {
    grade = 'C';
} else if (testscore >= 60) {
    grade = 'D';
} else {
    grade = 'F';
}
```

You can go check out this link for further infos : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 1):

You have the curly brace(s) in the wrong place. Formatting your code will make it more readable and easier to find syntax errors.

```
if (mean >= 90 && mean <= 100) {
  grade = 'O';
} else if (mean >= 80 && mean < 90) {
  grade = 'E';
} else if (mean >= 70 && mean < 80) {
  grade = 'A';
}
//.... the rest of your statement
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the if/else statement.  if you are trying to compare additional conditions then you should use "else if" as seen below.

```
 if(mean >= 90 && mean <= 100){
            grade = 'O';
       } else if (mean >= 80 && mean < 90) {
            grade = 'E';
       } else if(mean >= 70 && mean < 80) {
            grade = 'A';
       } else if(mean >= 55 && mean < 70){  
            grade = 'P';
       } else if(mean >= 40 && mean < 55){ 
            grade = 'D';
       } else if(mean < 40) { 
            grade = 'T';    
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to write an if-statement, and in this case, you are mixing the 2 together.

You can have an if with exactly one else, like so:

```
if(x == 1) {
    System.out.println("one");
} else {
    System.out.println("two");
}
```

Or you can use one if with multiple else-if statements:

```
if(x == 1) {
    System.out.println("one");
} else if(x == 2) {
    System.out.println("two");
} else if(x == 3) {
    System.out.println("three");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `else` only once per `if`. For this problem of yours, try `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces are too early, they should look like this:

```
    if(mean >= 90 && mean <= 100){
        grade = 'O';
    } else if(mean >= 80 && mean < 90){
        grade = 'E';
    } else if(mean >= 70 && mean < 80){
        grade = 'A';
    } else if(mean >= 55 && mean < 70){
        grade = 'P';
    } else if(mean >= 40 && mean < 55){
        grade = 'D';
    } else if(mean < 40){
        grade = 'T';
    }
```